# How to measure the latency of a GRPC backend written in golang

Tags: performance, grpc-go

I am a junior backend developer who created a backend API service in gRPC using Go. I implemented the same API service using both REST API (goFiber) and RPC using gRPC. However, when measuring the API response time in Postman for both gRPC and REST in the local environment, I found that the one written in REST gave me an average response time of 5-12 ms locally, whereas the one written in gRPC took an average of 40 ms. This is contrary to what gRPC is supposed to perform.

Is measuring the latency performance of a gRPC backend with Postman the wrong method to do? Currently, I am trying to implement gRPC in a monolithic application for the performance advantage.

The API is sending data in the following format:

```
{
  "offers": [
    {
      "offer_id": 12345,
      "company_id": 987,
      "country_code": "US",
      "image": {
        "url": "https://example.com/image.jpg",
        "width": 800,
        "height": 600
      },
      "thumb_image": {
        "url": "https://example.com/thumb.jpg",
        "width": 200,
        "height": 150
      },
      "offer_names": {
        "en": "Sample Offer",
        "ar": "عرض نموذجي"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is the proto file for my gRPC:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package protobuf;

option go_package = "example.me/app-api/internal/protobuf";


message OffersRequest {
  string country_code = 1;
}

message Images {
  string url = 1;
  int32 width = 2;
  int32 height = 3;
}

message DateRange {
  int64 from = 1; // Unix epoch time in seconds
  int64 to = 2; // Unix epoch time in seconds
}

message Name {
  string en = 1;
  string ar = 2;
}

message Store {
  Name name = 1;
  StoreImage image = 2;
}

message StoreImage {
  string thumb = 1;
  string image = 2;
}

message CompanyImage {
  string thumb = 1;
  string image = 2;
  string thumb_ng = 3;
  string image_ng = 4;
}


message Cover {
  int32 offer_id = 1;
  int32 company_id = 2;
  string country_code = 3;
  Images image = 4;
  Images thumb_image = 5;
  Name offer_names = 6;
  Name validity_texts = 7;
  int64 valid_to = 8; // Unix epoch time in seconds
  bool featured = 9;
  int32 page_count = 10;
  bool offer_home = 11;
  DateRange sponsored = 12;
  int32 id_firm_sub_category = 13;
  Store store = 14;
}

message Company {
  int64 id_company = 1;
  int64 id_firm_sub_category = 2;
  string website = 3;
  string country = 4;
  CompanyImage images = 5;
  map<string, string> names = 6;
  map<string, string> descriptions = 7;
  int64 type = 8;
  int64 priority = 9;
  int64 count_visible = 10;
  string product_main_categories = 11;
  int64 adword_type = 12;
  string google_ad = 13;
  string details_tab_list = 14;
  string exclude_subcategory = 15;
  string store_url = 16;
  int64 store_url_text = 17;
  string store_contact = 18;
  int64 contact_type = 19;
  map<string, string> link_text = 20;
}


message OffersResponse {
  bool status = 1;
  string message = 2;
  repeated Cover offers = 3;
  repeated Company stores = 4;
}

service OffersService {
  rpc Offers(OffersRequest) returns (OffersResponse) {}
}
```

Can anyone give me an idea of what's happening here? I don't think it's an issue with the code because I tried sending a simple "Hello World" message in gRPC, and it took an average response time of 20 ms to 30 ms.

Comment: That sounds far too slow.  Please check out our benchmarking information at https://grpc.io/docs/guides/benchmarking/.  Our latency benchmarks (which are even a little smaller than your "Hello World") get ~180microseconds of latency to localhost for median latency.  (You can find them on https://grafana-dot-grpc-testing.appspot.com/?orgId=1)  Maybe you are creating a new connection for every RPC?

Answer (score 0):

The GRPC response time is most likely a result of using Postman to make requests to GRPC.

If you're translating HTTP requests to GRPC requests you're bound to have increased latency, you're practically making two TCP requests in one.